# How to include a module with Puppet

Tags: puppet

Here is a small exemple module :

```
class apache {
...
}
```

What is the difference between these two methods if i want to include my example module ?

```
node web1 {
include apache
}

node web1 {
class { 'apache:' }
}
```

What is the best practices to include a class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between those two approaches.  You would need to use the `class {'apache':}` format if you want to add class parameters.